# React-webcam: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, server-error

I am trying to use react-webcam, but it is showing below error on loading that page where react-webcam is imported. Note I am not using angular in the project.

`Server Error
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Call Stack

```
setPrototypeOf
<anonymous>
extendStatics
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (115:15)
extendStatics
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (118:8)
__extends
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (181:4)
react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (417:2)
call
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (30:29)
__webpack_require__
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (94:17)
eval
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (97:10)
factory
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (3:19)
eval
node_modules/react-webcam/dist/react-webcam.js (10:3)`
```

I have tried the solutions provided on similar question, nothing is working.

Comment: You should search on the project repository on GitHub and if there are no similar problems you should ask there. Make sure that you show your code, without the code no one will help you.